# Gatling tests increase number of constant users perSecond following pattern

Tags: scala, performance-testing, gatling

I have recently started to use [gatling](http://gatling.io/#/) for performance and load testing. According to their documentation there are several ways to send concurrent requests for example:

`rampUsersPerSec(1) to(100) during(1 minute)` which should increase the number of users per second linearly, however it has a lot of randomness to it. What I would like to do is send a constant number of requests per second, then pause, then increase the users by one, and repeat. Something along the lines of:

```
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._

class PricesSimulation extends Simulation {
  // ...
  // ...

  object GetPrices {
    // ...
  }

  val httpConf = http.baseURL("https://...")
  val scn = scenario("scenario1").exec(...)

  setUp(
    scn.inject(
      constantUsersPerSec(1) during(5 seconds),
      nothingFor(5 seconds),
      constantUsersPerSec(2) during(10 seconds),
      nothingFor(5 seconds),
      constantUsersPerSec(3) during(10 seconds),
      nothingFor(5 seconds),
      constantUsersPerSec(4) during(10 seconds),
      nothingFor(5 seconds),
      constantUsersPerSec(5) during(10 seconds)
      // ...
      constantUsersPerSec(100) during(10 seconds)
    ).protocols(httpConf)
  )
}
```

So basically I am trying to reduce everything in `setUp` to a for loop where I increment the arg of constantUsersPerSec by one (or the equivalent). However my scala knowledge is very limited and I failed miserably...

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
val steps = (constantUsersPerSec(1) during(5 seconds)) :: (2 to 100).toList.flatMap(i =>
  List(
    nothingFor(5 seconds),
    constantUsersPerSec(i) during(10 seconds)
  )
)

setUp(steps: _*).protocols(httpConf)
```